# Azure Traffic Manager Load Balance Options

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I tried to dig on MSDN but could not get concrete statement for which is the best load balancing method.

could someone please share some light on which of the below are best option for given scenario:

1. Performance
2. Failover
3. Round Robin.

Scenario:

x Web Roleshosted on Large VM on single data center.

Requirement:
must be 100% up 24x7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

First: Do you really want to offer a 100% uptime SLA for your customers, when Azure itself doesn't offer 100% in its [SLA's](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/)?

That said: Traffic Manager only load-balances your *compute*, not your *storage*. So if you're trying to increase uptime by having a set of backup compute nodes running in another data center, you need to think about data access speed and cost:

- With **round robin**, you'll now have distributed traffic across multiple data centers, guaranteed, and constantly. And if your data is in a single data center (which is a good idea to have data in a single System of Record, unless you have replication logic all taken care of), some of your users are going to see increased latency as the nodes separated from your data are going to be requesting data across many miles (potentially between continents). Plus, data egress has a [$$$ cost to it](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/).
- With **performance**, your users are directed toward the data center which offers them the lowest latency. Again, this now means traffic across multiple data centers, with the same issues as round robin.
- With **failover**, you now have all traffic going to *one* data center, with another designated as your failover data center (so it's for High Availability). In the event you have an outage in the primary data center, you'd now have a failover data center to rely on. This may help justify the added latency and cost, as you'd only experience this latency+cost when your primary app location becomes unavailable for some reason.

So: If you're going for the high availability route, to help approach the 100% availability mark, I'm guessing you'd be best off with the **failover** model.

Comment: Say I wanted to have 2 app services (i.e. which I presume means different physical servers?) in the same data center and round robin between them, is that possible? As far as I can tell the Traffic Manager only allows end points from different data centers.

Answer (score 0):

Traffic manager comes into picture only when your application is deployed across **multiple cloud services** within same data center or in different data centers. If your application is hosted in a single cloud service (with multiple instances of course) , then the instances are load balanced using `Round Robin` pattern. This is the default load balancing pattern and comes to you without any extra charge.

You can read more about traffic manager here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/

Answer (score -1):

As per my guess there can not be comparison which is best load balancing method of Azure Traffic manager. All of them have unique advantages and vary depending on the requirement of application. Most common scenario is to use performance load balancing option with azure traffic manager. But as Gaurav said, you will have to have your cloud service application hosted on more than one cloud services. If you wish to implement performance load balancing then here is the link to get you started - http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2014/06/performance-load-balancing-using-azure.html